# Whats faster on mysql? Column per column handling or via index?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-web-services

I'm currently working on a cloud project. Its hosted on Amazon AWS and the data is stored in RDS (MySQL). I have many devices with many small requests, devices are asking the server for new commands to execute. The devices have some parameters like "power"=1 or 0, etc., so the commands are used to give the devices order what to do. Now there are two scenarios:

1. Every command is a column in the table "commands", the devices are asking and the server searches for commands with device=ID. "the classic style". Gives back the column and deletes it (2 Queries).
2. There is a table called "parameters", where all the "power", ... status things are placed , every line has a timestamp and the device too. So every request the server says: ok, the timestamp of the device is xxx, so which parameter was updated after this xxx.

The description is a bit complicated. Sorry for that. The point is: In the first idea there are not as many columns as in the second. But in the second the server has to check every cloumn for WHERE device=ID AND timestampx > 'device_time_stamp'. Every device asks every 5 seconds and there will be a lot of devices, so its a question about performance.

Thanks folks

Comment: 3. A properly normalized design

Answer (score 0):

On the limited information available, you might have something like this:

```
device_command
(device_command_id -- PK establishing a sequence for the commands
,device_id
,command_id
,completed -- either a simple 1/0 flag, or a timestamp
)
```

I'm not sure I understand how the 'parameters' fit into all this so I'll leave it at that for now.

Comment: the parameters are the things that should be transfered. Its all about bringing a simple information from a device to web and again to a device. its a smart home project. so i want to control a device via cloud